# Who heard the voice saying:this is my son in whom I am well pleased.. Was it people who stood by? Or John alone

Tags: kjv

> And behold a voice from heaven, saying, "This is My beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased." [Matthew 3:17 KJV]

> And there came a voice from heaven, *saying*, Thou art my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased. [Mark 1:11 KJV]

> Now it came to pass, when all the people were baptized, that, Jesus also having been baptized, and praying, the heaven was opened, 22 And the Holy Ghost descended in a bodily shape like a dove upon him, and a voice came from heaven, which said, Thou art my beloved Son; in thee I am well pleased. [Luke 3:21,22 KJV]

1. Was the voice heard  by people who stood by ?
2. Was the voice heard by John the Baptist alone ?

Comment: As with many other similar passages (Acts 9:4-7, 22:7-9), all heard a (loud) noise (Job 40:9; Psalm 77:18, 104:7; Ezekiel 1:24, 43:2; Revelation 1:15, 14:2, 19:6), but only the man of God was able to grasp its (true) meaning.

Comment: Please take the Tour and see the Help (both bottom left, below). I have edited out the advertisement as it is contrary to site rules. Welcome to BH.

Comment: We are not told who heard the voice from heaven.

Answer (score 2):

In the mouth of two or three witnesses let every matter be established, says the scripture,
Deuteronomy 19:15, Matthew 18:16 and 2 Corinthians 13:1. And here, three witnesses attest to a voice being heard from heaven.

These three are Matthew, especially chosen by Jesus Christ personally to be a witness of all that occurred during the ministry of Jesus Christ ; and Mark, who is approved by both Peter, the chief apostle and by Paul the most prominent ; and Luke who also is approved of Paul in his writing and accompanied him in his missionary journeys.

Matthew, the apostle of Jesus Christ says of the event :

> Behold ...

He tells his reader to behold what he is about to recount. And then he recounts the facts.

Nowhere do these three witnesses mention 'them that stood by'. I am assuming that those words are remembered, by the OP, from the matter of a voice being heard by 'them that stood by' when Saul of Tarsus heard a voice speaking to him. Those 'that stood by' (on that occasion) only were aware of a voice speaking. It seems that only Saul, later called Paul, was cognizant of the content of the speech.

Thus the documented record does not draw attention to 'those that stood by' on this particular occasion, nor do we have any information about what they did, or did not, apprehend.

The record is there for us to 'behold' ... certain things.

We - we, ourselves - are to behold : that a voice was heard and what the voice said.

> This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased.

Our attention is not to be on the crowd, on those that stood by. We are not even told what *John* heard. In the gospel account of the apostle John, John 1:28-34, we are told that John the Baptist testifies to the descent of the Holy Spirit upon Jesus and he declares, himself, that this is the Son of God. But whether, or not, John heard, or did not hear, the voice from heaven, is not - specifically - mentioned.

The revelation that Jesus of Nazareth is the Son of God is a *personal revelation*. One either sees it and testifies to it (as did John the Baptist) or one is unaware of it, by personal revelation, only able to repeat it from books or other people's words.

We are to behold that a voice spoke, we are to behold what the voice said.

We are to behold the One of whom it spoke.

I agree with @Dottard , in his comment :

> We are not told who heard the voice from heaven.

*We are to hear it for ourselves.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, all three gospel writers say, "a voice from heaven..." None of them write *they heard* or *John heard* nor did they write *I heard*. But clearly, a voice came out of heaven, or all three are liars. My personal take is, that they were there and that each writer hears "a voice from heaven".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Only John the Baptist heard the voice. His witness was recorded in John 1:32-34 (NIV)

> 32 Then John gave this testimony: “I saw the Spirit come down from heaven as a dove and remain on him.

> 33 And I myself did not know him, but the one who sent me to baptize with water told me, ‘The man on whom you see the Spirit come down and remain is the one who will baptize with the Holy Spirit.’

> 34 I have seen and I testify that this is God’s Chosen One.”

By the time Jesus was baptised, He hadn't picked His disciples yet. So neither Matthew, Mark, Luke and even John the Evangelist heard the voice. Now John the Baptist was the only witness, and he gave his witness to his disciples in John 1:32-34. Two of them heard the witness and they followed Jesus (John 1:37), one of the disciple was generally identified as John the Evangelist.

Did John the Baptist was the only witness? Not really. The Holy Spirit was the second. Therefore the witness is true.

Then why not everyone stood by could hear the voice? It is because revelation is a gift from the glorious Father.

John 3:3

> Jesus replied, “Very truly I tell you, no one can see the kingdom of God unless they are born again.”

Hebrew 12:14

> Make every effort to live in peace with everyone and to be holy; without holiness no one will see the Lord.

The people stood by were likely waiting in line to be baptised. They had not been borne again, neither by water or by the Spirit. Could they hear the voice?